# Create a new tree view in Odoo13

Tags: treeview, odoo-13

I´m trying to create a new tree view for the invoices in Odoo 13
my code looks like this:

```
<odoo>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="new_invoice_tree">
        <field name="name">New Tree</field>
        <field name="model">account.move</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="custom_field_1"/>
                <field name="custom_field_2"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="my_module.new_tree_action_window" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">New tree</field>
        <field name="res_model">account.move</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="new_invoice_tree"/>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="domain">[('type','=','out_invoice')]</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem name="Libro de ventas"
              id="my_module.new_tree_menu"
              parent="my_parent_menu"
              action="my_module.new_tree_action_window"
              sequence="1"/>

</odoo>
```

But when I try to open the menu appears this error:

```
Rastreo de error:
Error: Unknown field state in domain
    at Class.compute (http://192.168.1.7:8070/web/content/317-6c3bb5c/web.assets_backend.js:322:55)
    at evalModifier (http://192.168.1.7:8070/web/content/317-6c3bb5c/web.assets_backend.js:1197:91)
    at Class._evalModifiers (http://192.168.1.7:8070/web/content/317-6c3bb5c/web.assets_backend.js:1200:44)
    at Class._registerModifiers (http://192.168.1.7:8070/web/content/317-6c3bb5c/web.assets_backend.js:1401:101)
    at Class._renderBodyCell (http://192.168.1.7:8070/web/content/317-6c3bb5c/web.assets_backend.js:2076:70)
    at http://192.168.1.7:8070/web/content/317-6c3bb5c/web.assets_backend.js:2100:117
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Class._renderRow [as _super] (http://192.168.1.7:8070/web/content/317-6c3bb5c/web.assets_backend.js:2100:80)
    at Class._renderRow (http://192.168.1.7:8070/web/content/317-6c3bb5c/web.assets_backend.js:2010:69)
    at Class._renderRow (http://192.168.1.7:8070/web/content/312-75a923f/web.assets_common.js:3863:371)
```

I´m not sure how my domain should look like, what´s what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way to avoid this kind of error is by adding the "state" field with the attribute invisible as True, like this:

```
<odoo>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="new_invoice_tree">
        <field name="name">New Tree</field>
        <field name="model">account.move</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="state" invisible="True"/>
                <field name="custom_field_1"/>
                <field name="custom_field_2"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

This error appears on databases that are working with the Enterprise version of Odoo.